# php - Replace Template Code with HTML

Tags: php, regex

I got a Button, that creates this template code

```
[5afc4076e9f1b1526481014.pdf]##LINKNAME## (96.51 kb)
```

The filename and file size vary und the user can change the `##LINKNAME##`, as well.
This code goes to a database and when I get it back, I want to replace it to

```
<a href="5afc4076e9f1b1526481014.pdf" target="_blank">##LINKNAME## <i>(96.51 kb)</i></a>
```

I think I need to use `preg_replace()` but I am not really good at regular expressions.
I stopped here:

```
<?php
$string = ' [5afc4076e9f1b1526481014.pdf]##LINKNAME## (96.51 kb)';
$regex = '[[a-zA-Z0-9]+.pdf](.*?)\s';
$replace = 'I DONT KNOW';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $string);
?>
```

I know that this is a complete mess, but I'm not getting any results as long as I don't know the regex and the correct `$replace`.

Comment: does the ##LINKNAME## contain space? what characters are allowed in the LinkName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex: `^\[([^\]]+)\](\w+)\s\(([^)]+)\)$`

Replace with: `<a href="\1" target="_blank">\2<i>(\3)</i></a>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/139WL9/1)

Comment: Thank you! This is working perfectly. I'll take some time, understanding what you put there. Thank you for the Demo. This is really good to learn and understand!